# Permission denied in VVDocumenter-Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to use the plugin VVDocumenter-Xcode in Xcode v5.0.2, but it can't built. The error is:

`error: Unable to create directory: /Users/yangxinqiao/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/VVDocumenter-Xcode.xcplugin/Contents (Permission denied)`

Can anybody explain why I might be getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and write:

```
$ cd Library
$ cd Application\ Support
$ cd Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/
$ sudo chmod -R 777
```

Answer (score -1):

open terminal. 
go to VVDocumenter-Xcode source folder.

```
chmod -R 777 *
```

and try again.

Comment: probably navigate to ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/XCode and run chmod? Your answer seem senseless